# Rendering Windows 7 at 1366x768 but outputting 1024x768 resolution to display (using AMD HD7770)?

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, htpc

I have a Samsung 720p plasma with a native resolution of 1024x768, which is a non-square pixel format (4x3 resolution on 16x9 display).

Running Windows at 1024x768 looks nice and sharp, but the aspect is off.  Running at 720p (1280x720) makes the aspect ratio correct, but the output (especially text) quite blurry.

**What I want is to be able run Windows at 1366x768, but scale this output so the TV gets a 1024x768 resolution.  Is this possible?**

I would also consider running a Debian based Linux distro, but the Catalyst drivers have the same options so I don't know if that would help.

**EDIT**
http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/PN42C450B1DXZC-techspecs

I have also bolded my question, as it seems to be overlooked.

Comment: Well, have you tried the driver setting yet?

Comment: @user1306322, of course.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the TV doesn't have a normal 1:1 output option? Does the screen have non-square pixels or is it the software thing of the TV? How about different signal input method? SCART, RCA, HDMI, whatever?

Comment: @user1306322, the TV does have a 4:3 option that solves the aspect ratio, but then I end up with huge grey bars on either side and wasting screen space.  I'm using HDMI.

Comment: If the TV will accept analog VGA input, I'd try doing that while running Windows at 1366x768.

Comment: 1366x768 is not supported by the TV.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is running at display's native resolution and tweaking Windows ClearType settings to make the text look better.
And what do you exactly mean by blurry? Can you post a screenshot?

**UPDATE**
The native resolution is 720p(1280x720) since you mention its a 720p display.
And the pixels are always square, physically.
If you use a 4x3 aspect ratio resolution on 16:9 display, it will either stretch the picture thus distorting it OR it will show 2 black bars on either side.

AMD HD7770 should definitely output 720p; so set the resolution as 720p, adjust ClearType settings and if it still does not work out, please post a screenshot.

Although it doesn't really matter but what interface are you using? VGA/DVI/HDMI?

Comment: You misunderstand.  At the native resolution (1024x768) the text is fine; the aspect ratio is the problem.

Comment: No, it's native resolution is "1,024 x 768 Resolution", http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/model/PN42C450B1DXZC-techspecs and is just classified as a 720p.  Third time I'm telling you the native resolution.  And it's not a cleartype issue.  The issue in sending it 1280x720 is that it gets interpolated to 1024x768.

Comment: Also screenshot is useless because that's before the image gets resized by the screen.

Comment: Thats weird...they make a 16:9 panel with native resolution of 4:3....I don't think i can think of a solution to this!

Comment: Yes, that is the problem:  to have windows at 1366x768, but have the GPU scale it to 1024x768 for output to the display.  Non-square pixel displays are sort of common in HDTVs from a few years ago.

Comment: Well its gonna have to scale...if the panel has only 1024x768 physical pixels, how can it show 1366x768 pixels...

Comment: I want it to scale, but from 1366x768 and not from 1280x720.  The former is a higher resolution, and also doesn't require vertical scaling.  It will be much better quality.